# Ruby on Rails add nested controller/resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application that I want to have a route that is /admin/active_vulnerabilities but when I generate the controller as `rails generate controller ActiveVulnerabilities` and put the following in my routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users
    resources :active_vulnerabilities

    # Admin root
    root to: 'application#index'
  end
```

But I get the error `uninitialized constant Admin::ActiveVulnerabilitiesController` so I changed my controller to `class Admin::ActiveVulnerabilitiesController < ApplicationController`

I then get the error `Unable to autoload constant ActiveVulnerabilitiesController, expected /home/luke/projects/vuln_frontend/app/controllers/active_vulnerabilities_controller.rb to define it` but the file mentioned is my controller named exactly as that.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should be put in `app/controllers/admin/` because the namespace. Otherwise, you can forget this directory and the namespace and use just scope

```
scope :admin do
  resources :active_vulnerabilities
end

class ActiveVulnerabilitiesController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: I moved the controller to `app/controllers/admin/` and edited the routes file to show `namespace :admin do
    resources :users
    resources :activevulnerabilities
    # Admin root
    root to: 'application#index'
  end` but I still get the same issue

Comment: Try to restart the server